# Potree Zoom in/out on click

Tags: three.js

I am trying to zoom in/out when the user clicks the “+” or “-” buttons on my control panel. I got it to move left, right, up, down with the “tweenFunction” and it worked. I’ve tried

```
viewer.scene.camera.zoom += 0.1;
```

Which didn’t work for me because I don’t have the “camera” variable in my code, only the viewer. Here is my code

```
    setup();
    window.viewer = new Potree.Viewer(document.getElementById("potree_render_area"));

    viewer.setEDLEnabled(false);
    viewer.setFOV(60);
    viewer.setPointBudget(5*1000*1000);
    document.title = "";

    viewer.setBackground("gradient"); // ["skybox", "gradient", "black", "white"];
    viewer.loadSettingsFromURL();

    viewer.loadGUI(() => {
        viewer.setLanguage('en');
        $("#menu_scene").next().show();
        //viewer.toggleSidebar();
    });

    viewer.setDescription(`

    `);

    let sceneSG = new Potree.Scene();
    let sceneSG2 = new Potree.Scene();

    viewer.setScene(sceneSG);

  Potree.loadPointCloud("model.js", "model", function (e){

        sceneSG.addPointCloud(e.pointcloud);
        sceneSG.view.position.set(37.812, -26.781, 51.178);
        sceneSG.view.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(-53.587, 33.834, 28.864));


        let material = e.pointcloud.material;
        material.size = 1;
        material.pointSizeType = Potree.PointSizeType.ADAPTIVE;

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't access "directly" to viewer.scene.camera because potree has two cameras (a perspective one and an orthographic). But you can access to the active camera with this function:

```
viewer.scene.getActiveCamera()
```

So if you want to zoom in, it could look like this:

```
var myactivecamera = viewer.scene.getActiveCamera();
myactivecamera.zoom += 0.1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use activecamera for rotation? When i rotate now with active camera, it rotates in a big circle versus rotating from its center point.

Comment: @Jagr i have same issue. Did you solve it ?